# Automatically switch between SVN branches of the same project

Tags: linux, svn, environment-variables

How can developers set up their environment paths when working on different SVN branches of the same project so that they don't need to setup their paths each time they switch from one branch to another?

I am a Python developer and I find myself working on different branches of the same project and it's pretty ugly to export each time PYTHONPATH when I am switching from one branch to another.

That is if your IDE doesn't do this automatically for you (I am using vim).

Comment: Looks like you are doing something very wrong... are you properly using "svn switch" command?

Comment: Are you asking how to change an environment variable when you switch working copies?

Comment: I know how to switch environment variable ... I am asking if it could be done automatically, in case I forgot to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For another option, you could use a symlink, then have your environment variables point to it.  Like:

```
branch1/
branch2/
current -> branch1/
```

Then if you want to work on branch2 just point 'current' to it.  Your environment variables would point to 'current'.

Answer (score 1):

So your workflow is to keep separate branches in separate working directories?  That's fine, it's a pretty reasonable workflow with Subversion.

Personally I would change whatever Python programs you have in source control to look for their own libraries and modify `sys.path` before importing anything; that way they'll work no matter where they've been relocated to.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, sys
basedir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(basedir, 'lib'))
```

If you don't do that, you could put a wrapper executable in your `~/bin` or whatever, somewhere in `$PATH`,

```
#!/bin/bash
dir=$(pwd)
while [[ $dir != / ]]; do
    if [[ -d "$dir/lib" ]]; then
        export PYTHONPATH="$dir/lib${PYTHONPATH:+:$PYTHONPATH}"
        break
    fi
    dir="${dir%/*}"
done
if (($# > 0)); then exec "$@"; fi
```

which simply looks around for a `lib` directory to prepend to `$PYTHONPATH` before running whatever you want.  Maybe name it "`py`".

```
$ cd dir1          # dir1/lib exists
$ py ./my-program
$ cd ../dir2       # dir2/lib exists
$ py ./my-program
```

It's also possible to have a workflow where you stay within a single working directory, using [`svn sw`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch04s05.html) to change branches.  Since your path never changes, setting `PYTHONPATH` once would stay valid even with branch changes.

(This is the common workflow in [git](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout), monotone, hg, etc.)